# Invalid cast exception when using ShowViewModel<>(); using UITabBarController

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

After update from mvvmcross 4.4.0 to 5.0.5 method `ShowViewModel<SettingsViewModel>();` throws `System.InvalidCastException`. Output is:

```
mvx:Diagnostic:121.13 Showing ViewModel SettingsViewModel
iOSNavigation:Diagnostic:121.13 Navigate requested
mvx:Diagnostic:121.16 PresentationAttribute not found for SettingsViewController. Assuming animated Child presentation
```

and a StackTrace :

```
at MvvmCross.iOS.Views.MvxTabBarViewController.ShowChildView (UIKit.UIViewController viewController) [0x00007] in <091ad1c63ffa448eb48cc38964d45708>:0 
  at MvvmCross.iOS.Views.Presenters.MvxIosViewPresenter.ShowChildViewController (UIKit.UIViewController viewController, MvvmCross.iOS.Views.Presenters.Attributes.MvxChildPresentationAttribute attribute, MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest request) [0x0004a] in <091ad1c63ffa448eb48cc38964d45708>:0 
  at MvvmCross.iOS.Views.Presenters.MvxIosViewPresenter.<RegisterAttributeTypes>b__20_1 (UIKit.UIViewController vc, MvvmCross.iOS.Views.Presenters.Attributes.MvxBasePresentationAttribute attribute, MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest request) [0x00000] in <091ad1c63ffa448eb48cc38964d45708>:0 
  at MvvmCross.iOS.Views.Presenters.MvxIosViewPresenter.Show (MvvmCross.iOS.Views.IMvxIosView view, MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest request) [0x0002c] in <091ad1c63ffa448eb48cc38964d45708>:0 
  at MvvmCross.iOS.Views.Presenters.MvxIosViewPresenter.Show (MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest request) [0x00009] in <091ad1c63ffa448eb48cc38964d45708>:0 
  at MvvmCross.iOS.Views.MvxIosViewDispatcher+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<ShowViewModel>b__0 () [0x00016] in <091ad1c63ffa448eb48cc38964d45708>:0 
  at MvvmCross.iOS.Views.MvxIosUIThreadDispatcher.RequestMainThreadAction (System.Action action) [0x0001f] in <091ad1c63ffa448eb48cc38964d45708>:0 
  at MvvmCross.iOS.Views.MvxIosViewDispatcher.ShowViewModel (MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest request) [0x00022] in <091ad1c63ffa448eb48cc38964d45708>:0 
  at MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxNavigatingObject.ShowViewModelImpl (System.Type viewModelType, MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxBundle parameterBundle, MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxBundle presentationBundle) [0x0002c] in <ed129c02df414c1d8cea008ca80d94cb>:0 
  at MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxNavigatingObject.ShowViewModel (System.Type viewModelType, MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxBundle parameterBundle, MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxBundle presentationBundle) [0x00000] in <ed129c02df414c1d8cea008ca80d94cb>:0 
  at MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxNavigatingObject.ShowViewModel[TViewModel] (MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxBundle parameterBundle, MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxBundle presentationBundle) [0x00000] in <ed129c02df414c1d8cea008ca80d94cb>:0 
  at FreQuest.ViewModels.Tabs.MyProfileViewModel.<get_SettingsCommand>b__35_0 () [0x00001] in /Users/pavlomelnyk/frequest-ios-xamarin/FreQuest/ViewModels/Tabs/MyProfileViewModel.cs:114 
  at MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxCommand.Execute (System.Object parameter) [0x00009] in <ed129c02df414c1d8cea008ca80d94cb>:0 
  at MvvmCross.Binding.iOS.Target.MvxUIControlTargetBinding.ControlEvent (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs eventArgs) [0x00025] in <78be62c59fd541e38ea9b95c6cd03bdc>:0 
  at UIKit.UIControlEventProxy.Activated () [0x00007] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4691/d2270eec/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIControl.cs:38 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4691/d2270eec/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79 
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4691/d2270eec/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63 
  at FreQuest.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in /Users/pavlomelnyk/frequest-ios-xamarin/iOS/Main.cs:17
```

I invoke `ShowViewModel<SettingsViewModel>();` in MyProfileViewModel that is in UITabBarController that extends MvxTabBarViewController. My guess is somehow ViewModels related to TabBarContreller do not "see" SettingsViewController.
Has somebody face same issue? Your feedback will be very helpful.
Thanks

Comment: As i found out it is connected to this issue:
[link](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/1812)
The solution was to use this example:
[link](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples/blob/master/XPlatformMenus/XPlatformMenusTabs.iOS/Views/TabBarController.cs)

Comment: Making long story short. View controllers that are in tab bar controller has to be wrapped in navigation contollers
Example:

`private UIViewController CreateTabFor(string viewName, string title, string imageName)
        {
            var controller = new UINavigationController();
            controller.NavigationBar.TintColor = Colors.Primary;
            var screen = this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController(viewName);
            controller.PushViewController(screen, false);
            return controller;
        }`